# jboss change the web app context root?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web, jboss

so I have maven web app name `cus-cm`, and the pom.xml define version : `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`,and I set the web context root in eclipse properties: `cus-cm`. but when I run it on jboss-as-7.1 in eclipse, the jboss deploy the app into cus-cm-0.0.1-SNANPSHOT.war. so I have to access app by local:8080/cus-cm-0.0.1-SNANPSHOT/, I konw use jboss-web.xml and define `<context-root>` will help,but in the deployments directory is still  cus-cm-0.0.1-SNANPSHOT.war. what's more I have to remove jboss-web.xml everytime publish app to PaaS(I don't know the PaaS configuration). so can anyone help ?

Comment: Why must you "... have to remove jboss-web.xml everytime publish app to PaaS."?

Comment: @Steve C. thanks, cuz the paas deploy it as cus-cm as I wish,and if I keep jboss-web.xml. the url become cus-cm/cus-cm/, Idonot know how they config the paas

Comment: I think this is a support request to your PAAS provider.